# Non-option arguments in Git

Tags: git, macos

I'm trying to configure my gitconfig for a local directory

```
  hist = log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
```

This is what I'm trying to set it to but I get an error of fatal: option '--graph' must come before non-option arguments. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: This works as-is in the `[alias]` section of my git config.

Comment: I'm still very new to this but wanted to be sure.. I have a parent directory called hello. Do I make the .gitconfig in the same folder as my hello folder or inside of it?

This was the instruction: "Add the following to the .gitconfig file in your $HOME directory."

Comment: Git's got a few places to keep config entries with different scopes, the repo-local config is inside the repo directory, `.git/config` from the top of the work tree usually; your all-my-repos config is usually in `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config`. edit: there's more places for e.g. systemwide stuff, see the git config docs.

Comment: Got it. I made it inside my repo directory. When I run "git hist" it executes but nothing shows. I can do nano .gitconfig and it's there. Why is it not executing my aliases? Also, I don't see the .gitconfig file itself in the repo directory. Is this normal? I am using a mac OS

Comment: Never mind.. I put a space after the colon. Didn't know that made a difference. Works now

Comment: Ah, I was about to ask if you are using MacOS and found this in your comments. Yes, on macOS the `:` has special meaning. Slightly more details: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173529/when-did-the-colon-character-become-an-allowed-character-in-the-filesystem/173621 (P.S. I dunno how to proceed with it, but I think you need to escape `:` somehow to have this line be portable between OSes)